# "state" table that saves the score not working properly

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table, corona-storyboard

I'm writing the code that would save the scores to a "state" table and it would continuously accumulate until it reaches the result page. I use the table because it says table is better than using 'globals'. I'm having problems with the accumulation as the scoreText resets to 0 when jumping to the next scene.

main.lua

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )                 
local storyboard = require "storyboard"          
storyboard.state = {}
storyboard.state.score = 0                    
storyboard.gotoScene( "scene_splash" )
```

Question1.lua

```
local scoreText

function scene:enterScene(event)
...
    scoreText = display.newText( "0", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
    scoreText:setFillColor( 0,0, 0 )
    scoreText.x = 87
    scoreText.y = 28
    group:insert( scoreText ) 

if (event.other == balloons[1])  then
    scene.updateScore()
    print('Ball is colliding')
    balloon1.isVisible = false
    balloonText1.isVisible = false 
    audio.play(pop)
    storyboard.gotoScene("correctAnswer1", "fade", 1000)
end
end

function scene.updateScore()
   storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 50
   scoreText.text = storyboard.state.score
end
```

Question2.lua

```
local scoreText

function scene:enterScene(event)
...
if (event.other == balloons[3])  then
    scene.updateScore()
    print('Ball is colliding')
    balloon3.isVisible = false
    balloonText3.isVisible = false 
    audio.play(pop)
    storyboard.gotoScene("correctAnswer2", "fade", 1000)
end
end

function scene.updateScore()
   storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 50
   scoreText.text = storyboard.state.score
end
```

...

Comment: Where is your scoreText created, can you show that part of code? Also, if you fix the indent you'll see you have two `end` missing (one in each question file), please fix this.

Comment: Great. Please consider posting an answer and accepting it so it gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

I made a minor mistake in a line and i changed it to:

```
scoreText = display.newText( storyboard.state.score, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `enterScene` event does not have an `other` field so `event.other` is `nil` so the block of code where you call `score.update` does not get executed in either of the question scenes. You can check this by putting some `print` statements in update. The condition should be something else.